# Destination Host Unreachable on my local wireless network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

Situation :
- We have 2 local wifis 
- I have a laptop with windows 10 and linux mint.

My laptop succeeds in :

- go to local machines and internet on Windows in the two wifis
- go to local machines and internet on Linux Mint in one wifi
- go to internet only in the other wifi

Problems : I can't connect to local machine in one of my wifi, the main 192.168.1.90.

Here some informations :

```
$ ping 192.168.1.90
PING 192.168.1.90 (192.168.1.90) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.1.90 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7162ms
pipe 4

$  ip route show
default via 192.168.0.254 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.5.0.0/16 dev br-126a86a95b72 proto kernel scope link src 10.5.0.1 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-5585fcc14543 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-ffa00dae35d6 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-45c9b233fe89 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-696c6cd000f0 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-a5b107ce0f9c proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 linkdown 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-5e76bc95a6a2 proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-856bd7eecf34 proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-a00c552b4f42 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-ed526af94ec4 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-33bf868ab344 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 linkdown 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-2d66b6086cb5 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 linkdown 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-0be066dfc91e proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 linkdown 
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-16171ee240b7 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1 linkdown 
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-764b19df63f3 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.32 metric 600 
192.168.0.0/20 dev br-89e9fa1333df proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.16.0/20 dev br-87429f9b24a6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.1 linkdown 
192.168.32.0/20 dev br-e84b89dd855d proto kernel scope link src 192.168.32.1 linkdown 
192.168.48.0/20 dev br-c3bed90b0ffd proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.1 linkdown


$ ifconfig -a
br-0be066dfc91e: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.29.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.29.255.255
        ether 02:42:52:ce:d3:b0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-126a86a95b72: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.5.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 10.5.255.255
        ether 02:42:9e:8e:e3:95  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-16171ee240b7: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        ether 02:42:85:cb:f3:9c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-2d66b6086cb5: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.28.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.28.255.255
        ether 02:42:a7:0e:10:03  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-33bf868ab344: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.27.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.27.255.255
        ether 02:42:b0:2a:b5:e7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-45c9b233fe89: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.20.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:faff:fe69:892a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:fa:69:89:2a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 73  bytes 5547 (5.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 318  bytes 121622 (121.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-5585fcc14543: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        ether 02:42:c6:4f:b5:97  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-5e76bc95a6a2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.23.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.23.255.255
        ether 02:42:ca:1f:9a:10  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-696c6cd000f0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.21.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.21.255.255
        ether 02:42:c2:75:c8:56  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-764b19df63f3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.31.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.31.255.255
        ether 02:42:f5:b1:b5:f5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-856bd7eecf34: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.24.255.255
        ether 02:42:6e:a9:bb:b6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-87429f9b24a6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.31.255
        ether 02:42:2d:fd:e3:03  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-89e9fa1333df: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.15.255
        ether 02:42:72:70:de:ae  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a00c552b4f42: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.25.255.255
        ether 02:42:6b:e4:fc:ff  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-a5b107ce0f9c: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.22.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.22.255.255
        ether 02:42:8b:9e:a2:5d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-c3bed90b0ffd: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.48.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.63.255
        ether 02:42:6f:22:a7:ce  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-e84b89dd855d: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.32.1  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 192.168.47.255
        ether 02:42:f9:14:49:2c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ed526af94ec4: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.26.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.26.255.255
        ether 02:42:96:6d:81:b0  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-ffa00dae35d6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        ether 02:42:e7:e5:7a:ba  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a1:c3:c0:2a  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp1s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1c:39:47:32:7c:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 6591  bytes 681971 (681.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6591  bytes 681971 (681.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth1b38218: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c487:30ff:fe08:519e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c6:87:30:08:51:9e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 253  bytes 38631 (38.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth290129e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::3c5b:95ff:feff:7fa  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3e:5b:95:ff:07:fa  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 254  bytes 38718 (38.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth436bcde: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::dc11:64ff:fe5e:3dc3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether de:11:64:5e:3d:c3  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 257  bytes 39216 (39.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth439e161: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ac19:29ff:fe06:5092  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ae:19:29:06:50:92  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 261  bytes 39894 (39.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth658fbc9: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::44a1:a1ff:fe94:7e3e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 46:a1:a1:94:7e:3e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 253  bytes 38631 (38.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vetha19ccc2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::24a0:f2ff:fe3b:165f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:a0:f2:3b:16:5f  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 271  bytes 41636 (41.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethccdcf05: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::24d7:acff:fef7:486d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 26:d7:ac:f7:48:6d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 281  bytes 42918 (42.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethe6bb43c: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::689f:39ff:fe8e:595  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 6a:9f:39:8e:05:95  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 263  bytes 40088 (40.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vethf09464a: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5852:2fff:feb8:4967  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 5a:52:2f:b8:49:67  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 73  bytes 6569 (6.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 325  bytes 121561 (121.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.32  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a01:e0a:22c:b8d0:c450:bb70:23e3:6164  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a01:e0a:22c:b8d0:b69b:5793:cca4:2d59  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::1d28:34d7:8306:8ee6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e0:94:67:96:a4:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 216632  bytes 247780347 (247.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90443  bytes 19181402 (19.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If you need any other informations I can complete this issue

Comment: The second wifi interface is not yet initialized on your linux mint. It could be a simple driver problem. Can you post the output of `sudo dmesg` and `lshw -class network`?

Comment: You can see result here : https://justpaste.it/1pf0r

Comment: Are you sure you are using a usb wifi adapter? I can only see here is the internal wifi card and a bluetooth adapter

Comment: it's not a usb wifi adapter, it's an internal wifi card.